# How to retrieve a variable from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

Say we have a function named `shopping_cart()`, and inside it we have a list assigned to the variable `cart_items`. How would I be able to use this variable/list out side of this function?

Comment: The function should return the varriable. Then you can assign the result to a variable when calling the function.

Comment: Local variables are *not accessible outside of a function*, that is the entire point of local variables. If you need to access some object outside of that function, then your function should *return* that object to the caller.

Comment: if you don't need to return it you should to define it as global variable and use it anywhere you want, but you need to use "global cart_items" before use this variable in any function

Answer (score 1):

`return` cart_items.
Like this:

```
def shopping_cart():
    cart_items = ["apple", "banana"]
    return cart_items

items = shopping_cart()
print(items)
#['apple', 'banana']
```

[This](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#understanding-the-python-return-statement) website explains it fairly well, and you can find numerous others by looking it up.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to either return the variable or use a global variable. Other answers have returned the variable, so here's an example using a global variable:

```py
def shopping_cart():
    global cart_items
    cart_items = ["apple", "banana"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to access that variable because of scope. What you could do is declare that variable as a global variable and then change the value inside the function.

Here is an example:

```
def shopping_cart():
    global cart_items
    cart_items = ["some value"]
shopping_cart()
print(cart_items)
```

Comment: your code have a wrong , it print [], you cant access to cart_items  without " global cart_items" in function

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to return it you should to define it as global variable and use it anywhere you want, but you need to use "global cart_items" before use this variable in any function, like this code:

```
cart_items = ['hello']
def shopping_cart():
    global cart_items
    cart_items.append('world!')


print(cart_items)
#['hello']

shopping_cart()

print(cart_items)
#['hello', 'world!']
```

and you can return cart_items, like this code:

```
def shopping_cart():
    cart_items = ['hello']
    cart_items.append('world!')
    return cart_items


print(shopping_cart())
#['hello', 'world!']
```